# Trying to setup an iptables port 80 to 8080 redirect on debian 6

Tags: debian

When trying to setup a redirect and save the iptables file via iptables-restore, i get the following error:

```
iptables-restore v1.4.8: Line 31 seems to have a -t table option.

Error occurred at line: 31
```

Here's the full file, with the line im trying to use to redirect at #31

```
*filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections
# THE -dport NUMBER IS THE SAME ONE YOU SET UP IN THE SSHD_CONFIG FILE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Any ideas as to why it may not be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familar with this format, but I will give it a try. The mistake is mixing NAT with `*filter`. Should be something like follow

```
# Filter -- start

*filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections
# THE -dport NUMBER IS THE SAME ONE YOU SET UP IN THE SSHD_CONFIG FILE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT

# Filter -- end

# Nat -- start

*nat
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
COMMIT

# Nat -- end
```

I didn't test it. Feel free to correct me if I make an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the DNAT target if you wish. I have OpenERP running on a machine with IP 192.168.1.171. I forward incoming requests for port 80 to 8069 with the following rule:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.171 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.171:8069